# MySQL/PHP - ORDER BY name unless new

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple membership database; when returning the membership list, I ORDER BY surname... All simple so far.

I have a newMember field (a simple 0 or 1 TINYINT) which is used to toggle 'new' members for the administrator to approve.

I want to sort by surname but if newMember = 1 then put these at the top (preferable in surname order) to get a result like:

```
* NEW * Joe BLOGGS
* NEW * Simon CAMPS
* NEW * James ZULU
Sonny ALI
Daniel BRAVO
Addie WINDOW
```

I am certain there is way to do this with a CASE statement but cannot quite get my head around it... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add more field to the order clause

like:  `order by newMember desc, surname`

Comment: Doh! Yes this worked - for some reason I thought it wouldn't - I was doing `(SELECT memberID, memberApproved, memberFName, memberSName from tbMembers WHERE memberApproved = 0 ORDER BY memberSName ASC)
UNION (SELECT memberID, memberApproved, memberFName, memberSName from tbMembers WHERE memberApproved = 1 ORDER BY memberSName ASC) LIMIT 0,20` to get the same result!\

Answer (score 3):

The `ORDER BY` functionality can order by several columns.

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY newNumber, surname
```

It will first sort on newNumber and when it is equal to another row it then sorts on surname. You can also specify sort order for each by using `ASC` or `DESC` after the column name.

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
  SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY newMember DESC, surname
```

It will order them by the newMember flag ... then order the similar ones by the surname

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`select * from members order by newMember desc, surname`